# Source request for a GPL-licensed Linux kernel module?

Tags: gpl, source-code, linux-kernel

We have a CrowdStrike kernel module installed, and this is apparently the license:

```
description:    CrowdStrike Pinned Security Module
author:         CrowdStrike, Inc.
license:        GPL
retpoline:      Y
rhelversion:    7.4
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions
```

`license: GPL` would seem to indicate that source code is available for this module, but I haven't seen it anywhere online, including at https://github.com/CrowdStrike

I also noticed that it's listed as `intree: Y` but I don't see this in the kernel source tree.

Is anyone aware of the source code for this module being available anywhere? Are they being sneaky with "intree"?

If not, has anyone gone through the process of asking a vendor for source code for a kernel module?

Comment: That `vermagic` string looks a lot like a RedHat naming convention... I'd maybe figure out what version uses the 3.10.x kernel series and check that source.

Comment: @ivanivan it's not in the RH7 kernel sources either

Answer (score 5):

I know it may be late now but if you still have that version of the binary module, you can ask for the source code by emailing to legal@crowdstrike.com. Apparently they have now switched to proprietary kernel modules but if you have a version of the older binary with GPL license, you can ask for the source code. Please see [here](https://github.com/CrowdStrike/community/issues/24#issuecomment-840248373) for details.

Answer (score 3):

If that module is under the GPL (and AFAIK there is no way for a Linux kernel module not to be covered by the GPL), then whoever gave you these binaries is also responsible for providing you with the corresponding source code. If you have obtained this software via RedHat, then RedHat should be the target of your source request.

Comment: The module is from CrowdStrike - but I'm not sure where to go to ask for the source. There's a way for kernel modules to be proprietary, but typically they're not as that limits what symbols they can link to.

Comment: I think the "intree" part is untrue. It's built for my specific RedHat kernel but is not in that source tree.

Comment: @craig65535 for the GPL compliance aspect it is irrelevant who *authored* the module, only who gave you a *copy*. So it might be best to determine as part of which RPM the module was installed, and to use the contact info for that package to obtain or request the corresponding source.

Comment: The source of the rpm used to install this software is CrowdStrike. They are both the author and the distributor. Do I email them to ask for source code? I expect they would ignore me, because if they wanted to share source it would already be on their github. This is why I asked if anyone has gone through this kind of thing before.